# Is this a correct explanation of the asymptotic bias of maximum likelihood?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias

I want to be sure I understand, so please critique the following:

In regular parametric statistical models, the non-linear maximum likelihood estimator is biased. Given some data, $y_i$, parameters, $x_k$, the maximum likelihood estimate of $\beta$ is the value of $\beta$ which maximizes
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^nf(y_i|x_k; \beta)\hspace{0.3cm} \text{or}\hspace{0.2cm} \sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(y_i|x_k; \beta).
\end{equation*}
Let the log-likelihood be denoted as
\begin{equation*}
l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(y_i|x_k; \beta).
\end{equation*}
The estimated log-likelihood is
\begin{equation*}
   l_n(\beta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(y_i|x_k; \beta),
\end{equation*}
and the maximum likelihood estimate is the solution of setting the score equal to zero
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\partial l_n(\hat{\beta)}}{\partial \beta}= \sum_{i=1}^n l'_n(\beta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n l'(\beta)=0.
\end{equation*}
Clearly $l_n(\beta)$ and its derivative are of scale $1/n$ and thus can be written as power series in $1/n$. Taking a Taylor expansion about the true value $\beta$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial l_n(\hat{\beta)}}{\partial \beta} =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial l(\beta)}{\partial \beta_r} + (\hat{\beta}_s-\beta_s)\frac{\partial^2 l(\beta)}{\partial\beta_r\partial\beta_s} + \frac{1}{2}(\hat{\beta}_t - \beta_t)(\hat{\beta}_u - \beta_u)\frac{\partial^3l(\beta)}{\partial\beta_r\partial\beta_t\partial\beta_u} + ... =0.
\end{equation*}
The bias of the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\beta}$ is defined as $b(\beta)=\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta} - \beta)$, and thus it follows that the asymptotic bias can be written as
\begin{equation*}
    b(\beta) = \frac{b_1(\beta)}{n} + \frac{b_2(\beta)}{n^2} + \frac{b_3(\beta)}{n^3} + ...,
\end{equation*}
where $n$ is the sample size, assumed to be large relative to the number of parameters, $k$.

Comment: I think the standard refgerence is  See formula 20 in Cox, David R.; Snell, E. Joyce (1968). "A general definition of residuals". Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B. 30 (2): 248–275. JSTOR 2984505. Yoiu can access 100 articles a month for free